# The built-in keyword type means a function or a class in python?

Tags: python, types, metaclass

In most posts, people often say `type` is a built-in function if it is provided with one argument, and it is a metaclass if provided with 3 arguments.

But in [python's doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=type#type), the signature of `type` is:

```
class type(object)
class type(name, bases, dict)
```

So, does it means `type` is a built-in class and not a built-in function even if it is provided with one argument?

Comment: Well, it can’t be both – but it acts like a function when passed one argument.

Comment: I think it should be your answer: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-type-objects

Comment: `type` is not a keyword.  Examples of keywords are `for`, `in`, or `as`.  You can't name a variable `for` but you can name a variable `type` (legal but strongly not recommended!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`type` is called a "metaclass" because it's a class that produces other classes (AKA types). It behaves like a normal class. In particular, it has the equivalent of a `__new__` method that would look something like this in Python:

```
class type(object):

    def __new__(cls, *args):
        num_args = len(args)

        if num_args not in (1, 3):
            raise TypeError('type() takes 1 or 3 arguments')

        # type(x)
        if num_args == 1:
            return args[0].__class__

        # type(name, bases, dict)
        name, bases, attributes = args
        bases = bases or (object,)

        class Type(*bases):
            pass

        Type.__name__ = name

        qualpath = Type.__qualname__.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
        Type.__qualname__ = '.'.join((qualpath, name))

        for name, value in attributes.items():
            setattr(Type, name, value)

        return Type

Class = type('Class', (), {'i': 1})
instance = Class()

print(type(instance))  # -> Class
print(instance.__class__)  # -> Class
print(type(type(instance)))  # -> type
print(Class.i)  # -> 1
print(instance.i)  # -> 1
```

Note that when instantiating a class, the value of the new instance is whatever is returned from [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__). In the case of `type`, `__new__` always returns a type object (AKA class). Here's an example of a class that extends `int` to use `-1` as the default value instead of `0`:

```
def Int__new__(cls, *args):
    if not args:
        return cls(-1)
    return super(cls, cls).__new__(cls, *args)

Int = type('Int', (int,), {'__new__': Int__new__})

i = Int()
print(type(i))  # -> Int
print(i.__class__)  # -> Int
print(type(type(i)))  # -> type
print(i)  # -> -1

j = Int(1)
print(j)  # -> 1
```

To really dig into how `type` works, take a look at [the C code in `type_new`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L2326). You can see there (scroll down a few lines) that `type(x)` is a special case that immediately returns the type (AKA class) of `x`. When you do `type(name, bases, dict)`, the type creation machinery is invoked.

For more fun, try the following:

```
type(object)
type(type)
isinstance(object, object)
isinstance(type, object)
type(1)
type(type(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

The distinction between classes and functions in Python is not as stark as in other languages.

You can use function call syntax to invoke an actual function, but also an instance of a class with the `__call__` method, and even a class that overrides `__new__` can behave like a function.

The word Python uses for all these is **callable**: an object you can invoke using the call syntax (`foo()`), which evaluates to a result.

The `type` built-in is a `callable`. It can be called.

Sometimes you treat `type` like a function, and it works, so you can say it's a function. Other times you treat it like a class, so you can say it's a class. The actual implementation should not matter.

This is duck typing in action: [if it walks like a duck, and it quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Comment: All classes are callable whether they override `__new__` or not.  The question is regarding the built-in `type`.  Duck typing is the principle of classifying an object by its behavior rather than by inheritance.  Not related.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `type` always returns a *type object*, which is basically a class.  That's true whether it's the one-argument form or the three-argument form.  In the one-argument case, the returned object is the *type* (class) of the argument.  In the three argument case, the returned object is a new *type object* (class).  In both cases the returned object can be used to instantiate new objects (instances of the class).

Some classes can be used as metaclasses.  That's a common use case for the three-argument form of `type`.  But there are other ways to make a class that can be used as a metaclass, and other uses for the three-argument form of `type`.

It's not that much different from `int`, which is a built-in function that returns an object of type `int`.  `int` is also the name of a class, and can be used to create new objects:

```
>>> x = int()
>>> x
0
>>> type(x)
<class 'int'>
```

And also like type, it has more than one form:

```
>>> y = int("A", 16)
>>> y
10
```