# How do you read documentation in python

Tags: python

*Headsup: I have started with python 2.6 about 2 hours ago. Been doing Java, C, etc. till now*

**TL;DR**

In Java I want to understand what is an Object, I look at the [javadoc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)
Where do I find a similar clear documentation of what a function does in python?

---

**Long story**

I understood the following

1. A variable 'a' is not restricted to a given datatype.
2. A variable 'a' can hold an 'int' and a 'float' at different points in time.

Ended up with a simple code and out of curiosity checked up [type()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/402507/1897935)

```
a = 1     # type(a) is int
a = 1.2   # type(a) is float
a = 1     # type(a) is int
```

Wanted to understand what **type()** in python really does and found [type function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type)
that reads '*class type(object)*' but [Built-in data-types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types#Built-in_Data_types) has no mention of either 'class' or 'object'

when i read 'class type(object)' I interpret it as

1. there is a function called 'type'
2. this accepts an object as a **parameter**
3. this **returns** a class

But python documentation is contradicting saying "return the type of an object. The return value is a type object." and the code snippet at the documentation seemed to be creation of a class which made no sense either.

```
a = False # type(a) returns 'bool'
```

[Built-in data-types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types#Built-in_Data_types) talks about Boolean, so where is **bool** documentation located?

Comment: `type` is itself a class (similar to Java's `java.lang.Class`). For each type (which may be a class inside Python or a type from a compiled binary extension) there exists an object of type `type`.

Comment: If possible you should begin with a newer Python version, at least 2.7 but much better 3.4 or later.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, regarding version: I was officially asked to study python from [here](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/introduction). the tutorial recommended me **While we recommend "avoiding" Python 3 for now, recognize that it is the future, as all new features are only going there.**

Comment: A wrote [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47007160/8651755) about `type` that you might be interested in.

Comment: Also, there's [this page](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) in the Python docs that talks about objects and types, including `bool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wanted to understand what type() in python really does

In Python, everything is an object.  So when you see this:

```
class type(object)
```

It is telling you that it accepts an object (generically) and returns a "class" which is also an object.  A class in Python is an object which describes other objects--a "meta object" if you prefer.  This is by contrast to e.g. C++, where a class is not an object at all (it cannot be stored).

In Python, types are objects, so for example `type(type(type('hello')))` gives you `type` (because the result of the `type()` function is always a type object).

Comment: did understand the answer but one big doubt remains, [Data Types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types#Built-in_Data_types) has no mention of object. so is object a datatype? or no?

Comment: @SrinathGanesh `object` is a data type and is similar to `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: @SrinathGanesh: `object` is the ultimate base class of everything in Python.  Try `isinstance(x, object)` for any x.

Comment: No, the notation class type(object) doesn't mean it returns a class but that type **is** a class.

Comment: Ok **object** is a *data type*. Java Object is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), Where is Python object documented at?? None at [data types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types#Built-in_Data_types)

Comment: `type` is a class that is the root class of all classes; `type` is _also_ an object. `type(x)` _always_ returns a type (AKA class) and the returned type/class is _also_ an object. You can verify this with `isinstance(type, object)` and `isinstance(type(x), object)`.